# Azure web App is ignoring web.config URL rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I have an azure web app. It is deployed as a framework dependant app targeting net8.0 and the runtime target is portable.

I have written a web.config which is in the wwwroot directory.

I am trying to use a url rewrite to redirect the default domain sitename.azurewebsites.net to my actual website https://sitename.com I dont want the default site accessible.

The web app seems to ignore my web.config no matter what I try. The web.config contents are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sitename\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://sitename.com.au/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\sitename.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Ive tried changing the publishing the web.config to the server, i can confirm it is in the site root. Azure is just ignoring it.

Comment: Have you added in local and deployed or are you using the default web.config file?

Comment: I have created the web.config in the wwwroot directory and published it with the app. Ive used the Azure App Service editor to check the contents of the root directory on the server and I can see that web.config is there. I can also see that its settings have not been transformed during the deployment. So it seems like azure is just ignoring web.config or I have the settings in web.config incorrect somehow.

Comment: @user3500162 Place your web.config file in the root directory of your project, rather than keeping it in the wwwroot folders.

Comment: Have you tried CustomDomain ?

Answer (score 0):

> The web app seems to ignore my web.config no matter what I try

It ignores because we need to place web.config file in the root directory of the project, rather than keeping it in the wwwroot folders.
When we publish ASP.NET Core applications, it creates a web.config file by default in home/site/wwwroots in KUDU.

[image]

In the below code I used https://www.google.com as Redirect URL.

**web.config**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect requests to default Azure Websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^urlrewritingapp2024\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.google.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\sitename.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Here's the **web.config** file after the deployment.

[image]

Here's the successful output:

My actual URL is https://urltest12024.azurewebsites.net and its Redirected to Google.com

[image]